# C# Class library - resource files not loading

Tags: c#, localization, resources, assemblies, resx

I am working on adding localisation to my class library. Currently I have two resource files: Strings.resx and Strings.es.resx.

Both files are under the 'internal' access modifier, although I have tried setting both to 'public' without any help.

My problem is that the Spanish resource file (Strings.es.resx) is not being loaded; and this problem will repeat with any more resource files I add for other languages. The Strings.resx works fine as it is the default resource file.

This code is used to grab which string resource files have been loaded; currently only the default file is loaded. Spanish does not appear:

```
private static void LoadLanguages()
    {
        var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

        foreach (var culture in cultures)
        {
            try
            {
                var rs = Properties.Lang.Strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false);
                if (rs != null) SupportedLanguages.Add(culture.Name.ToLower(), culture.NativeName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }

        Log.Info("Loaded languages: " + SupportedLanguages.Count); //OUT: 1
    }
```

I have made a discovery though. In my build output, there is a folder "es", and within that folder is a DLL called `Project.resources.dll`. If I copy that DLL to the root folder of the build output, the resource gets loaded.

The solution to this problem is to get those resource files loaded from the folders. For some reason this is not happening. Is there a known solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works out the threads current culture. An example can be seen in the docs over at Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-satellite-assemblies-for-desktop-apps (check code at step 13 in the end)

Below the example from the documentation. The localized resource is `StringLibrary`

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] cultureNames = { "en-GB", "en-US", "fr-FR", "ru-RU" };
      Random rnd = new Random();
      string cultureName = cultureNames[rnd.Next(0, cultureNames.Length)]; 
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
      Console.WriteLine("The current UI culture is {0}", 
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name);
      StringLibrary strLib = new StringLibrary();
      string greeting = strLib.GetGreeting();
      Console.WriteLine(greeting);
   }
}
```